# Getting force close while scrolling down the list View in Android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, baseadapter, android-logcat

I am getting force close errors while I try to scroll down my list View in fragment activity, which has 1 image View and 2 text view. I am beginner in android, so don't have that much knowledge except basic scenario in mostly used components of android.

No bitmap OOM error is there, as I checked without images too.

I am retrieving images from sd card from the path.

Here, is my logcat out put with errors.

```
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at com.example.prac.HomeUser$ReceiptAdapter.getView(HomeUser.java:861)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2588)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:681)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:645)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:6535)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3664)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4492)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7677)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2395)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2305)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1575)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2470)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2253)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7875)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3978)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3862)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5105)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5084)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5182)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:174)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5155)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5201)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-05 18:07:02.868: E/AndroidRuntime(3257):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now here is my code..

```
class ReceiptAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<GetterSetter> receiptlist;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // private int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#C8A6DA"),
    // Color.parseColor("#F6F4AB"), Color.parseColor("#A2C3D0"),
    // Color.parseColor("#F1B4A1") };

    private int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#2280aee3"),
            Color.parseColor("#22888888") };

    public ReceiptAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<GetterSetter> receiptlist) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.receiptlist = receiptlist;
        // inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        // inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext());
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return receiptlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent,
                    false);

            // if (position % 2 == 1) {
            // convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            // } else {
            // convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            // }

            int colorPos = position % colors.length;
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.Total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);
            holder.Img = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            Animation animation = null;
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                    R.anim.wave);
            animation.setDuration(200);
            convertView.startAnimation(animation);
            animation = null;

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.Title.setText(receiptlist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.Total.setText(receiptlist.get(position).getTotal());

        String path = receiptlist.get(position).getImg();
        File fileImg = new File(path);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (fileImg.exists()) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 7;



            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileImg.getAbsolutePath(),
                    options);

            // bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileImg.getAbsolutePath());
            holder.Img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        else
        {
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.no_image);

            holder.Img.setImageBitmap(icon);
        }

        holder.Img.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView Title;
        TextView Total;
        ImageView Img;
    }


}
```

and my async task in which in postExecute() I am calling the custom list adapter as,

```
ReceiptAdapter adapter = new ReceiptAdapter(getActivity(),
                        recList);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

So, my question is where am I getting wrong?

I have searched many codes also on stackoverflow, too but I found the same errors of others but didn't get any good feasible solution, so if anybody could help me out in this, then it would be appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Your holder is `null`, always. In method `getView` you assign null to holder.
In else you should assign tagged object to holder.

In your method, getView():

```
{
//...
} else {
holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
```

Comment: Heyoo! @DeadFish , THANK YOU SO MUCH! It is working now very well! You are intelligent! Thanks a tone! :) :D

Comment: Heyaa @DeadFish Can you tell me after implementing your solution, listview is now without force close working, but it is not smooth on scrolling.. so to make listview scrolling smoothly, what should I do??

Comment: If anybody else can reply me!!

Comment: please create new question topic and describe the question